# Не отображаются данные в PageMenu при первом запуске в swift

Tags: ios, swift

У меня есть ViewController и в нем снизу имеется [PageMenu](https://github.com/uacaps/PageMenu) как MainCollectionViewController.

При первой загрузке приложения загружаются данные с сервера, и должны отобразиться в PageMenu. Как отобразить данные сразу при первой загрузке приложения?

Вот внизу в PageMenu пусто.

Но после второй загрузки все работает.

Comment: Надо смотреть код

Comment: Скорее всего надо обновить view, но надо смотреть код.

Comment: Выложил проект сюда https://github.com/zhanswift/HalykNews

Comment: не работает в xcode8

Comment: Проект на Swift 2.3 и XCode 7.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разберитесь с потоками. Весь UIKit не является потокобезопасным и все работы с классами этой библиотеки должны вестись на главном потоке(main thread). В вашим случае это управление refreshControl, activityIndicator, обновление collectionView.

С этим вам может помочь GCD:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

})
```

Или NSOperation:

```
NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock() {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Не всегда данные успевают загрузиться до показа. Требуется добавить в функцию, которая тянет данные с сервера, [Completion Handler](https://thatthinginswift.com/completion-handlers/).